# iOS, inconsistency with devices / iOS version ringer muting sound?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I’ve been trying to detect when the sound cannot be heard in my app. I thought I had this working perfectly.

However after testing a couple of Apple apps and comparing it to my own I notice that the ringer mutes sounds for all apps in different environments.

On my iPhone 4s with iOS 9.3, the ringer will mute sound volume.

However on iOS 11 on several devices the ringer does not mute sound.

I just wonder if this is a known bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How the mute switch affects sounds depends on the app's AVAudioSession categories and options. Different apps, or different versions of the same app, may have different AVAudioSession categories and options. So you're seeing different behaviors on different devices because you're looking at different apps or, if they are the same app, different versions of the app, with different AVAudioSession categories and options.